# Error: HTTP Error: 400, Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "skipLog": Cannot find field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to setup firebase functions for the first time. I followed the steps in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), but when I run `firebase init functions` I run into this error:

> Error: HTTP Error: 400, Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
> "skipLog": Cannot find field.

Here is the extract from the `firebase-debug.log` file:

```sh
[debug] [2022-04-20T08:53:35.659Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<my_project_name>/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com:enable {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"skipLog\": Cannot find field.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"description":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"skipLog\": Cannot find field."}]}]}}
[error] 
[error] Error: HTTP Error: 400, Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "skipLog": Cannot find field.
[debug] [2022-04-20T08:53:35.670Z] Error Context: {
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"skipLog\": Cannot find field.",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
          "fieldViolations": [
            {
              "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"skipLog\": Cannot find field."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 400
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem, managed to init functions with older version (10.6.0) of firebase-tools

Comment: Yes I tried to use a previous version just before you answered, it worked too.

Answer (score 8):

To uninstall and reinstall using version 10.6.0:

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools@10.6.0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the problem for me.

```sh
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash
```

```sh
-- Checking for existing firebase-tools on PATH...
-- Your machine has firebase-tools@10.7.0, attempting upgrade...
-- Checking your machine type...
-- Downloading binary from https://firebase.tools/bin/linux/latest
######################################################################## 100.0%#=#=#                                                                         
-- Setting permissions on binary...
-- Checking your PATH variable...
-- firebase-tools@10.8.0 is now installed
-- All Done!
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions based on the answer here and it worked perfectly for me to get past the same error. Should we then later re-upgrade the firebase-tools at a later time?

To uninstall and reinstall using version 10.6.0:

`npm uninstall -g firebase-tools npm install -g firebase-tools@10.6.0`